# I don't know how to fix my code , it doesn't work properly

Tags: c++

I have a question about c++ and a problem which I have to solve. Actually, I wrote a code but the online judge gives me 70 from 100 and says that my code is not working correctly for 3 test cases. I can't find the bug to correct it, I would appreciate if anyone can help me. Thanks

I want to print the output for every 2 natural numbers a, b which make a/b fraction.
for example for the number (2) it should print 1 1 in the output because we don't consider (0,0) and the second point which we reach in the coordinate on the spiral path is (1,1).
the input should be a natural number and the output should be vertical and horizontal coordinate.

for example, the input is 12 and its output is 2 2.
more information is here in these photos:

[image]

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,j,x,y,count;
    unsigned int n;
    x=0;
    y=0;
    count=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=30000;i++)
    {
        if(i%2!=0)
        {
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                x++;
                count++;
                if(count==n)
                {
                    cout<<x<<" "<<y;
                }
            }
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                y++;
                count++;
                if(count==n)
                {
                    cout<<x<<" "<<y;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                x--;
                count++;
                if(count==n)
                {
                    cout<<x<<" "<<y;
                }
            }
            for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                y--;
                count++;
                if(count==n)
                {
                    cout<<x<<" "<<y;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This proves again how valuable online judges are to learn C++. (Sorry.) If a program doesn't work properly it's on you to debug it and to find out what's broken. _is not working correctly for 3 test cases_ So, these are the cases you have to focus on in debugging. These are probably edge cases you didn't consider properly. (To find edge cases which break an otherwise working algorithm is a crucial part of S/W development in general.) So, the first part is already done - just do the 2nd part.

Comment: @Scheff's Cat
I tried a lot; at first I put for every i<1000 and I got 50 from 100; by testing different numbers I reached to i<30000 and got 70; for more than it I get "Time Limit Exceeded" error.

Comment: This is a hint that they are looking for a trick you didn't notice. The time complexity of your naive implementation is too bad. Counting on this, they probably included a test case to provoke this. That's often the case, that they ask for a trick - a clever algorithm with a much better time complexity, e.g. an analytical approach (a simple formula) instead of an iteration. - Btw. "naive" is no offense. It is how certain (mostly the most simple and obvious) approaches are usually called.

Comment: To give you an example: Just for fun, I once answered yet another question about an online judge problem. Thereby, I compared the naive with an analytical approach (just to be sure that I did the latter correctly). [SO: Hackerrank Buying show tickets Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43950659/7478597)

Comment: @Scheff's Cat
 Thank you for your help. I tried again, but as I new to c++ , I could't fix it.

Comment: A minor note: Every natural number is _either_ even _or_ odd. This popped in my mind when I saw `if(i%2!=0)` ... `else if(i%2==0)`.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat 
I know that, because of that I put this constraints; you mean I should change them?

Comment: I mean the `else if(i%2==0)` is not necessary. Just an `else` results in the precisely same effect.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat oh yes, I tried it but nothing is change, i get 80 from 100 in online judge. actually I asked from some other people, they couldn't find the bug and unfortunately my teacher doesn't answer my email. I don't know what to do!

Comment: I've googled a bit concerning [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral). I somehow have the feeling that your kind of spiral might be similar and related to that. (Measuring distances by adding x and y distance is what I know as [Manhattan norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).) This is the direction I would research into. Maybe, this can lead to an analytic solution of your problem to overcome the TLE. (Unfortunately, I'm too less talented concerning math to provide a concrete approach.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat thank you so much for your help. I will check them

Comment: @Armin Montigny
Hi, can you please help me find my bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm maybe a little bit too complicated. Especially running loops **always 30000 times**, even while not necessary, is wasting time somehow.

And, if you want to request numbers for input > 30000, it will also not work.

The loop should be rewritten as: `for (i = 1; count <= n; i++)`. Then is should be better.

---

If you just want to have xycoordinates for a spiral pattern, you may do the following design and then implement it. Looking at the picture, we see the follwoing:

- We will have 2 times (for 2 directions) the same distance or length for a line
- Then, if we work on one line with a given distance or length, we always add the same delta value of wither 1 or -1 to a coordinate.
- After we have worked one 1 line, we will add delta values to teh other coordinate. If it was x before than it will be y now and vice versa
- To do that, we can store the coordinates in an array with length 2. Index 0 is for x and index 1 is for y.
- So, if we want to address either x or y, we can use a selector, a index, that will be either 0 or 1.
- We can toggle this selector after one distance or one line has been done
- After we have worked on 2 distances or 2 lines,we needto change the delta values, becuase from then on coordinated need to be decremented now. The same for vice versa.
- Additionally, after 2 distances or lines have been done, we will increase the distance or length to be used next time by 1.

So, look at the pricture and implement accordingly.

Please see one of many solution proposals:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    // Get user input. How many steps shall we go in our spiral
    unsigned int numberOfSteps{};
    std::cin >> numberOfSteps;

    int coordinate[2]{};            // Here we will store the xy coordinate. Index 0 = x, index 1 = y
    int xySelector{};               // This will select either index 0 or 1 , so, either x or y

    int delta{ 1 };                 // This will be added to a coordinate part, to get the next point of the line

    int distance{ 1 };              // Length of line. Will be used 2 times, then incremented
    int distanceCounter{ 1 };       // Down counter for distance
    int doSameDistanceCounter{ 2 }; // We will do always 2 lines with the same distance/length

    // Do the game for the requested number of steps
    for (int i{}; i < numberOfSteps; ++i) {

        coordinate[xySelector] += delta;    // Calculate next point of line

        --distanceCounter;                  // Keep track of length of line
        if (distanceCounter == 0) {         // Did we calculate one complete line?
            xySelector = 1-xySelector;      // Yes, then now use the other coordinate 
            --doSameDistanceCounter;        // Keep tract of number of same line length to use
            if (doSameDistanceCounter == 0) {   // If we did 2 lines with the same length
                doSameDistanceCounter = 2;      // Reset this counter
                ++distance;                     // Frome now one the length of line will be 1 more
                delta = -delta;                 // And the delta changes, fo increment or decrement operation changes
            }
            distanceCounter = distance;     // Reset distance/length counter to current needed distance
        }
    } // Show result
    std::cout << coordinate[0] << ' ' << coordinate[1] << '\n';
}
```

I tested it in release mode with 10M and the result was ultra fast.

---

Edit: And now the analytical solution

Drawing picture in Excel, we can see a pattern.

[image]

From this pattern, we can derive a formula.

That willresult in the following code which will never TLE.

Have fun:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <cmath>

int main() {

    // Get user input. How many steps shall we go in our spiral
    long long steps{};
    std::cin >> steps;
    
    // Calculate result
    const long long roundedSquareRoot = std::llround(std::sqrt(steps));
    const long long roundedSquare = roundedSquareRoot * roundedSquareRoot;
    const long long ddistance = std::abs(roundedSquare-steps) - roundedSquareRoot;
    const long long rsrIsOdd = (roundedSquareRoot % 2);

    const long long x = (ddistance + roundedSquare - steps - rsrIsOdd) / (rsrIsOdd ? -2 : 2);
    const long long y = (-ddistance + roundedSquare - steps - rsrIsOdd) / (rsrIsOdd ? -2 : 2);
    // Show ouput
    std::cout << "\n\n" << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I corrected my loop. I understand your code completely, your comments were so useful and made the code understandable. I also tried your code on the online judge, but the problem isn't solved. It gives Time Limit Exceeded error for three test cases! But your code helped me understand the problem better, I also didn't know that we can initialize by using {} and I've learned it now. Thank you so much, I really appreciate. @Armin Montigny

Comment: Hm, still TLE . . .  Then obviously the written algorithm is wrong and there may be an analytical solution. Can you add a link to the original requirements? I woud like to know the input ranges and the time constraints. Then I could check again.

Comment: In fact, it is a classroom exercise defined on an online site that only students can access. I do not know how to send the link of original requirements @Armin Montigny

Comment: You could take a screenshot of the task and then press the **edit** button under your question and paste the picture into it. I am sorry, but without more input I cannot optimize the code more . . .

Comment: yeah,I understand that , but the problem is that the question is written in persian. @Armin Montigny

Comment: I find out that one test case is 100000000000 (11 zeros) @@Armin Montigny

Comment: Then the data type "int" is not sufficient. "int" must be replaced by "long long". But this will still take 3 minutes to calculate. Then, the algorithm is wrong, and we need to look for a new one.

Comment: @pantea. I added the fastest possible solution. This will not TLE.

Comment: WOW! I don't know what to say and how to appreciate you. It was about a week that I had gotten stuck in this problem and you solved it. Thank you so much. Can you please explain me the code? I understood the picture but I can't understand the code . @Armin Montigny

Comment: You could accept the answer by clicking on the small checkmark beneath my answer . . .

Comment: I don't know how you understand to make ddistance (how to find the algorithm?) and then what rsrIsOdd exactly do and how you found you should make this formulas for x and y? these are my problems, I would appreciate if you explain it. @Armin Montigny